# how to draw <hr> like line with text in the middle in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create the following layout: there is an *hr* style line, which I know how to make, but I am not able to place text (OR) over it, and likewise create two *hr* lines with text in the middles doesn't seem possible using relative layout. Any tips on how to accomplish this?

[image: here is how it looks like]

Comment: Create on centered `TextView`, and create two lines to the left and right of it.

Comment: Should be possible with a nine patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without any drawables for the lines.

For the lines on either side of the "OR", simply make Views with height 1 (or whatever thickness you want), and with the background color you want and place them appropriately.

Give the following a try:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <Button android:id="@+id/signInButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="SIGN IN WITH GOOGLE"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/or"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/signInButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:text="OR"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <View android:id="@+id/leftLine"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#777777"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/signInButton"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/or"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/or"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"/>

    <View android:id="@+id/rightLine"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#777777"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/or"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/signInButton"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/or"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"/>    

</RelativeLayout>
```